# Jquery Appended Content - Not Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following JQ. It's basically adding a little icon that will allow for some inline editing when a list item is selected. However, I am unable to work with the jquery added content. I cant even log anything to console when I click my JQ added content. Is there something wrong with my code below?

I can not add a fiddle, because I dont have a link to the Kendo UI libraries, that this list is using.

```
  <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#treeview-left li").click(function () {
                            $("div#EditEntity").remove();
                            $(this).find(".k-state-focused").append("<div id='EditEntity'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' id='EditWindow'  class='icon-pencil active tiny'></a></div>");
                    });
                    $(".k-state-selected").on("click", "a#EditWindow", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.get("ClassificationEditEntity", function (data) {
                            $(".k-window-content").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need [**delegated event**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as html is dynamically added after DOM load:

```
$(".k-state-focused").on("click", "a#EditWindow", function (e) {
  console.log("Asdf");
  $.get("ClassificationEditEntity", function(data) {
    $(".k-window-content").html(data);
  });
});
```

or:

```
$(document).on("click", "a#EditWindow", function (e) {
      console.log("Asdf");
      $.get("ClassificationEditEntity", function(data) {
        $(".k-window-content").html(data);
      });
    });
```

See [**HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) at the last of the page details of delegated events.

Comment: I've updated my code, but it still does not work.  Is there soemthign I missed?

Comment: no you have not missed any thing can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: is ` .k-state-focused` also added to DOM after page load?

Comment: I can't do fiddle, it asp.net. I also do not have the kendo resources to make this work.

Comment: THe state-focused and state-selected are added after dom

Comment: then use `document` instead of it

Comment: Thank you!! What is the difference thought?

Comment: for delegated event we have to give closest parent element which is added to DOM on page load, as your that element was also added after DOM load we have document which is parent of all elements so that do the job or also we can use body element as it is also loaded on DOM load