# Click event not working on new inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ol class='addmenow'>
  </ol>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
  $('.addmenow').append("<li class='removemenow'>" +  " " + ($(this).attr('data-value')) + "  </li>")
 })
```

I can not get this to work:

```
<script>
  $('.removemenow').click(function(){
    alert('hello')
  })
</script>
```

Is this because each li element is added AFTER the DOM already loaded? Thus, '.removemenow' in the click event is essentially undefined? I am not getting any errors in the console. The idea is to be able to add an li element to a div and remove it if clicked.

Any insight would be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939966/jquery-appended-content-not-clickable/24940012#24940012

Comment: `$('.addmenow').on('click', '.removemenow', function(){})`

Comment: Yes, it is because you added after the dom was loaded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 $('.addmenow').on('click', '.removemenow', function(e){
    alert('hello');
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Use **event delegation method** for dynamically created elements.

Comment: You should really show him the *good way* to use event delegation : closest static parent. `$('.addmenow').on('click', '.removemenow', function(){})`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just tried this and it worked perfectly. I'll be able to accept this in 8 minutes. Thanks again!